# How to add a button to a single row in a one column TableView?

Tags: java, button, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView with a single Column and I want to have a Button in the last row of that TableView/Column. The Button should be disabled until a row is selected and then it should be enabled. I've done numerous searches on this but everything I've found seems to be adding a button to every row within a multi-column table. Is there a quick way to do this?

Here are some sample images:

[image]

**TableButtonView.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="406.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tablebutton.TableButtonController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="60.0" layoutY="22.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Agency Customization">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="40.0">
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Agency:  " />
                  <TextField fx:id="agencyTextField" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
                  <Button fx:id="addButton" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#onAdd" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="67.0" text="_Add">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <TableView fx:id="agencyTableView" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="276.0">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="agencyColumn" prefWidth="188.0" text="Agency" />
               </columns>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TableView>
            <ButtonBar maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
               <buttons>
                  <Button fx:id="okAgencyButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onOK" text="OK" />
                  <Button fx:id="cancelAgencyButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCancel" text="Cancel" />
               </buttons>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" right="20.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </ButtonBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**TableButtonController.java:**

```
package tablebutton;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableButtonController implements Initializable {

    private WebView helpWebView;
    @FXML
    private TextField agencyTextField;
    @FXML
    private Button addButton;
    @FXML
    private TableView<String> agencyTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<String, String> agencyColumn;
    @FXML
    private Button okAgencyButton;
    @FXML
    private Button cancelAgencyButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        agencyColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue())
        );
        agencyColumn.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");

        ObservableList<String> agencies = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    "AA","DL","LH");
        agencyTableView.getItems().addAll(agencies);
    }    

    @FXML
    private void onAdd(ActionEvent event) {
    }


    @FXML
    private void onOK(ActionEvent event) {
        // Just exit for now
        Stage stage = (Stage) okAgencyButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onCancel(ActionEvent event) {
        // Just exit for now
        Stage stage = (Stage) cancelAgencyButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

}
```

**TableButton.java:**

```
package tablebutton;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TableButtonView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) loader.load());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Button Test");
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your images the button is not part of the `TableView` (at least as far as I can tell). Furthermore the use case is not clear to me: Controls allowing removal of elements are usually positioned outside of the `TableView` itself and deleting a value from a single column only is also pretty unusual, since this was a removal results in all the elements with a higher index being modified too...

Comment: @fabian I had to do a picture and try to make it look like the button was part of the table since I don't know how to actually make it part of the table. My customer wants to be able to click on the button once they select an item from the table and delete that item from from the table. I know how to do that part. I argued against the way they wanted it but was overridden.

Comment: Makes me wonder why the "Add" button is outside of the `TableView`. Furthermore the more items you add to the table the less useable the table gets, since it takes longer to scroll to the bottom-most row using the scroll wheel or arrow keys. You could achieve a result like this by inserting an additional item and treating this item differently in the `cellValueFactory` returning a `Button` wrapped in an `ObservableValue` instead of a property of the item. Needless to say that this requires additional modifications, since `TableView` was never meant to be used this way:

Comment: (E.g. selection model, comparator.) Also this makes using any cell type but the default one impossible. A clean approach would require you to implement your own skin probably requiring you to write multiple k loc.

Comment: @Salome Don't put the button in the TableView, just use a VBox which contains the the TableView and the Button, with appropriate constraints so that the Button butts right up under the TableView and is sized to the width of the TableView.  Bind the disable property of the Button to an [empty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) [selected items set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--).

Comment: @fabian thanks for all the guidance and explanation.

Comment: @jewelsea I was able to implement what you suggested and it works as I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to put the button actually inside the TableView is problematic and not recommended.  There is a technical difficulty in getting the button to render in the last row of the TableView (this is not trivial), and there are also potential usability issues (what if there are a lot of rows in the table and the table needs to be scrolled, does the remove button just scroll out of view? if so, then how would a user find it if they wanted to remove something).

Instead, don't put the button in the TableView:

1. Use a VBox which contains the the TableView and the Button.
2. Set appropriate constraints so that the Button butts right up under the TableView and is sized to the width of the TableView.
3. Bind the disable property of the Button to an empty selected items set.

[image: Remove not selected] [image: Remove selected]

Sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Remover extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<NamedColor> colors = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new NamedColor("red", Color.RED),
                new NamedColor("green", Color.GREEN),
                new NamedColor("blue", Color.BLUE),
                new NamedColor("indigo", Color.INDIGO)
        );

        TableView<NamedColor> table = new TableView<>(colors);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        TableColumn<NamedColor, String> colorNames = new TableColumn<>("Colors");
        colorNames.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        table.getColumns().add(colorNames);

        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.disableProperty().bind(
                Bindings.isEmpty(
                        table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                )
        );
        remove.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        remove.setOnAction(event ->
                table.getItems()
                        .removeAll(
                                table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                        )
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(table, remove);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Remover.class);
    }

    public static class NamedColor {
        private String name;
        private Color color;

        public NamedColor(String name, Color color) {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your help worked perfectly for me @jewelsea Thank you